# Javascript IF statement not returning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a simple javascript code to generate a random door (either door1 or door2, and if door1 is generated, the phrase 'you win' appears.

Right now, despite if door1 or door2 is generated, the output is still 'you lose'. What am I doing wrong?

```js
let doors = ["door1", "door2"]

function selectDoor() {
    const randomDoor = doors[Math.round(Math.random())]
    console.log(randomDoor)
}

if(selectDoor() === "door1") {
    console.log('you win')
} else {
    console.log('you lose')
}
```

Comment: `selectDoor()` isn't returning anything so its always false.

Comment: Don't forget to properly select a random element from `doors`. `Math.round(Math.random())` will only give you a 0 or 1 which is why it works in this case where you only have two doors. If you added another door, you would see the problem. You can fix this using `doors[Math.floor(Math.random() * doors.length)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning `randomDoor` from `selectDoor`.

```
function selectDoor(){
  const randomDoor = doors[Math.round(Math.random())]
  console.log(randomDoor)
  return randomDoor
}
```

Returning nothing is equivalent to returning `undefined` which is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), effectively a `false` when used with comparison operators.

Comment: That did it, I was just missing the return. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should return the value in the function

```
let doors = ["door1", "door2"]

function selectDoor(){
const randomDoor = doors[Math.round(Math.random())]
console.log(randomDoor);
return randomDoor;
}


if(selectDoor() === "door1"){
    console.log('you win')
} else {
    console.log('you lose')
}
```